# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: fancy-buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, haml, sass, compass-sass

I am seting up an existing rails project. But found an error below on installation.

**Error:** File to import not found or unreadable: fancy-buttons.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: fancy-buttons.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/home/cis/Desktop/manish1/hamlncompass/app/assets/stylesheets/partials/_buttons.sass)
 /home/cis/Desktop/manish1/hamlncompass/app/assets/stylesheets
 /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.alpha.4/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.alpha.4/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
Compass::SpriteImporter
(in  /home/cis/Desktop/manish1/hamlncompass/app/assets/stylesheets/partials/_buttons.sass)):
```

Comment: Does your project have a fancy-buttons CSS file somewhere?  Was this project originally written on a 2.x version of rails?

Comment: Double check that you don't have a phantom Rails server running - this error can be caused by it. Try `ps aux | grep rails` and see if there any entries when you don't expect them.

Comment: How are you importing 'fancy-buttons' exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and the change involved changing:

`@import filename` to `@import filename.css.sass`

Comment: I've no idea why, made no sense to me at the time either~

Comment: Did the file name contain a period? I had a similar problem with including javascript: file names with periods required explicit extensions.

Comment: By convention I never use any periods in the file name unless it is denoting the file type; so no it was not - just like the above, it was like `filename.css.sass` but would not work as my above example. Funny thing was it was working at some prior point before, though I never figured out why

Comment: Same issue and your answer helped. The asset pipeline is still a bit of a mystery to me to be honest!

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble getting a production server to work (both a local Apache/Passenger setup and the built-in WEBrick server).

The browser was redirected to the 500.html error page, and the log kept saying `[GET /] miss`. When I reloaded the page repeatedly, eventually I would receive an output similar to what Manish reported.

My Sass files each contained an `@import 'base'` statement to load common color and font definitions. Changing this to `@import 'base.css.scss'` and having `config.assets.compile =` **`true`** in `config/environments/production.rb` made both production servers work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your system is looking for the partial file, either the manifest for your stylesheets isn't getting precompiled, or this isn't your answer:

I just had a similar problem with a system that worked fine in development, but not in production with assets precompiled.  I had used a secondary layout for my sign up/in pages that included it's own manifest file for the stylesheets.  Since `rake assets:precompile` only compiles `application.css` by default, my `signup.css` wasn't precompiled and I got an error similar to yours when I hit the sign in page.

I fixed this by adding the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(signup.css)
```